# Plotting a 3D data-set from a .csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a `.csv` with 2-dimensional data. Now I am trying to plot it in different index ranging from `-n:1:n` (this index is `y-axis`).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
T3,v11
0,0.66582
0.000125,0.66582
0.00025,0.66582
0.000375,0.66582
0.0005,0.66582
0.000625,0.66582
0.00075,0.66582
0.000875,0.66582
0.001,0.66582
0.001125,0.66582
}\dummydata
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,4},
]
{
    \addplot3 table [x =T3, y expr=1, z=v11, col sep = comma]
      {\dummydata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This throws errors like:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: The requested list entry with index 1 of
>   \dummydata i s too large; this list has not enough elements..
>
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.27       {\dummydata};
>                      This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend that
> ```
>
> you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by
>   order and method.
>
> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'T3' from
>   table ''. Please check spelling (or introduce name
>   aliases)..
>
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.27       {\dummydata};
>                      (That was another \errmessage.)
> ```
>
> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'v11' from
>   table ''. Please check spelling (or introduce name
>   aliases)..
>
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.27       {\dummydata};
>                      (That was another \errmessage.)
> ```
>
> Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all
>   have been  filtered away) on input line 27.
>
> [warning /pgfplots/warning/plot without coordinates]
>
> Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in
>   direction z). R eplacing it with a default range and clearing all
>   plots. on input line 29.
>
> [warning /pgfplots/warning/empty range cleared axis] LaTeX Font Info:
>   External font `cmex10' loaded for size (Font)              <7> on
>   input line 29. LaTeX Font Info:    External font`cmex10' loaded for
>   size (Font)              <5> on input line 29.

However, instead of using a `.csv` format, if I stick with a table format (that is removing a comma between the data and also `col sep = comma` in the plot, then I get what I desired. However, the data I have is in `.csv` format (pretty big). So, instead of creating a huge data-set for `y-axis`, how can I achieve it  with the above-mentioned script.

The one that works without a `.csv` format (and without creating a huge data-set for a different axis per-se):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{
T3 v11
0 0.66582
0.000125 0.66582
0.00025 0.66582
0.000375 0.66582
0.0005 0.66582
0.000625 0.66582
0.00075 0.66582
0.000875 0.66582
0.001 0.66582
0.001125 0.66582
}\dummydata
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,4},
]
{
    \addplot3 table [x =T3, y expr=1, z=v11]
      {\dummydata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which would give me the desired output:

[image]

> PS: This is just an example, in reality I use the external file to import my data for plotting purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After moving `col sep=comma` to the right place, the errors are gone.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{
T3,v11
0,0.66582
0.000125,0.66582
0.00025,0.66582
0.000375,0.66582
0.0005,0.66582
0.000625,0.66582
0.00075,0.66582
0.000875,0.66582
0.001,0.66582
0.001125,0.66582
}\dummydata
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0, ytick={1,...,4},
]
{
    \addplot3 table [x =T3, y expr=1, z=v11]
      {\dummydata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**MINI-EXPLANATION**: When you load the data, you need to tell `pgfplots` what the structure of the file is, i.e. how it is supposed to decompose it into rows and columns, i.e. cells. If you do not tell `pgfplots` that the columns are separated by commas, say, it will *assume* they are separated by spaces or tabs, which is why your second example worked. In your first example, `pgfplots` "thought" the first non-header row has only the cell `0,0.66582` rather than two cells `0` and `0.66582`, and so on, which explains the error messages. And yes, I can see how this might be confusing, after all you specify only in the plot which column goes where.

Comment: Nice answer, could you briefly explain why we must do that change?

Comment: @Raaja I added some mini-explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the little brief, its clear for me now!